# jQuery Accordion: Open item with achor from other page

Tags: jquery, hash, anchor, accordion

I am quit new at jQuery. 
From the homepage I have 4 links to the accordion page.
for example: http://pluscoating.falcondesign.nl/poedercoaten/#2
This must open the accordion with ID 2.

I figured out how to add an active class after the hash. Now the problem is, that the 'active' class were placed after the 'a' element. But it must be add after the class 'acc-trigger'. So how can I do this?

My html code:

```
<div>
    <span class="acc-trigger">
        <a id="1" href="#">Title 1</a>
    </span>
    <div class="acc-container">
        <div class="content">content 1</div>
    </div>
    <span class="acc-trigger">
        <a id="2" href="#">Title 2</a>
    </span>
    <div class="acc-container">
        <div class="content">content 2</div>
    </div>
    <span class="acc-trigger">
        <a id="3" href="#">Title 3</a>
    </span>
    <div class="acc-container">
        <div class="content">content 3</div>
    </div>
    <span class="acc-trigger">
        <a id="4" href="#">Title 4</a>
    </span>
    <div class="acc-container">
        <div class="content">content 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
(function() {

    var $container = $('.acc-container'),
        $trigger   = $('.acc-trigger');

    var hash = window.location.hash.substring( 1 );

    $container.hide();
    $trigger.first().addClass('active').next().show();

    if( hash ) {
        var accordItem = $('.acc-trigger a#' + hash);
            $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
            accordItem.addClass('active').next().show();
    }       

    var fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true);
    $trigger.css('width', fullWidth);
    $container.css('width', fullWidth);

    $trigger.on('click', function(e) {
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(300);
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });


    // Resize
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true)
        $trigger.css('width', $trigger.parent().width() );
        $container.css('width', $container.parent().width() );
    });

})();
```

Comment: as a side note, are you sure that the document has only one element with ids 1, 2, 3, 4 etc? Because id should be unique in a pag.

Comment: If all element id are unique then you can simplify the selector `'.acc-trigger a#' + hash` to just `'' + hash` which will be more efficient

Comment: On the page the elements have a unique ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if( hash ) {
    var accordItem = $('.acc-trigger a#' + hash);
    $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
    accordItem.closest('.acc-trigger').addClass('active').next().show();
}
```

Another solution is to trigger a click event after the click event handler is registered

```
(function() {

    var $container = $('.acc-container'), $trigger = $('.acc-trigger');

    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    $container.hide();
    $trigger.first().addClass('active').next().show();

    var fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true);
    $trigger.css('width', fullWidth);
    $container.css('width', fullWidth);

    $trigger.on('click', function(e) {
                if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
                    $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
                    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(300);
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            });
    //move this line to down after the click event handler
    if (hash) {
        $('.acc-trigger a#' + hash).triggerHandler('click');
    }

    // Resize
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
                fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true)
                $trigger.css('width', $trigger.parent().width());
                $container.css('width', $container.parent().width());
            });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks your first solution will help